# problem on java: not found

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line, bash, java

```
Initializing InstallScape using JVM at /home/manoj/iscap/iscape/runtime/LNX86/bin/java. This might take some time...
/home/manoj/iscap/iscape/bin/iscape.sh: 209: exec: /home/manoj/iscap/iscape/runtime/LNX86/bin/java: not found##
```

iam trying to install ic610 cadence.. but during iscape installation i got this error.. my installation goes to terminate..  i also installed jdk...

```
manoj@Greenchip:~$ sudo sh /home/manoj/ic610/IC610_lnx86.Base/CDROM1/SETUP.SH
sudo: unable to resolve host Greenchip


Copyright 1985-2006 by Cadence Design Systems Inc.

LICENSED SOFTWARE - REVERSE ASSEMBLY, REVERSE COMPILATION AND
REVERSE ENGINEERING PROHIBITED. The information contained in 
this package is the proprietary property of Cadence Design Systems,
Inc., or its licensors, and may only be used in accordance with 
the Cadence Design Systems license agreement under which this
package is provided.

Restricted Rights Notice to Government Users

Use duplication or disclosure by the Government is subject to 
the restrictions as set forth in subparagraphs (c)(1)(ii) of the 
Rights in Technical Data and Computer Software clause at 
DFARS 252.227-7013. Unpublished - all rights reserved under the 
copyright laws of the United States. 

Cadence Design Systems, Inc.
555 River Oaks Parkway
San Jose, California 95134 USA



Located CDROM at /home/manoj/ic610/IC610_lnx86.Base/CDROM1 

Specify path of install directory [OR type [RETURN] to exit]: /cadence

Detecting  InstallScape for lnx86...
Checking InstallScape on media...

Could not detect an InstallScape for lnx86 platform using the  PATH environment variable


It is a good idea to have only one Installation of InstallScape 
for lnx86 platform. If an InstallScape installation exists 
please help us find it.

Do you have InstallScape for lnx86 platform installed somewhere [y/n]?n

You are on  lnx86 platform
InstallScape version 03.40.p06 
for platform lnx86 
is available on this CD.

Do you want to install InstallScape for lnx86[y/n]:/iscape
Please press y (yes) or n (no) : y

It is recommended that you install InstallScape
outside the Cadence installation hierarchy
and include the ~iscape/bin in your PATH environment variable.


Type the path to InstallScape installation directory [ (q to quit)]: /iscape

InstallScape installation directory: /iscape

Extracting InstallScape version 03.40.p06
for platform lnx86 in /iscape


Starting up InstallScape in GUI mode 

DISPLAY environment variable is set to :0.0

If you do not see the InstallScape console 
window or the it seems to be hanging then kill this 
process.

Set your DISPLAY environment variable to a proper
value and manually start InstallScape by typing: 
/iscape/iscape/bin/iscape.sh /home/manoj/ic610/IC610_lnx86.Base/CDROM1:::/cadence 

Initializing InstallScape using JVM at /iscape/iscape/runtime/LNX86/bin/java. This might take some time...
/iscape/iscape/bin/iscape.sh: 209: exec: /iscape/iscape/runtime/LNX86/bin/java: not found
manoj@Greenchip:~$
```

- system config: using wubi installer 25GB allocated for ubuntu.
- 4GBRam
- software config: UBUNTU 12.04

Comment: well do you have Java installed? because it says you haven't...

Comment: yes i have java.... i installed JDK..

Comment: update your question with the output of `java -version`

Comment: problem cleared.. thank you sir.. for you guidance.. that software is x86 but my machine is x64... thats why java makes error

Answer (score 0):

I have developed the following guide in order to install Cadence SW in ubuntu/debian 64bits distributions:

**http://vlsi.die.upm.es/?page=staticContent&staticPageName=vlsi_sw**

It has been tested with ubuntu 13.10 (64bits).